# Trouble while applying padding in form element

Tags: html, css, padding

This is a snapshot of a basic form webpage, while changing the values of padding the gray background is not shrinking.

[image: Image of webpage]

I have attached an image of the CSS code. In that, I am using padding = 20px, but in the image only top and bottom padding is 20px, left and right padding is much beyond.

[image: Image of code]

I am applying styling on form element.

Here is the complete HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>StartUp survey form</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <h1 id="title">StartUp survey form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for taking the time to help us improve the platform</p>
    <form id="survey-form">
    <div>
        <label for="name" id="name-label">Name<br>
            <input id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text">
            <br>
        </label>
        <label for="email" id="email-label">Email<br><input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br></label>
        <label for="number" id="number-label">Age(optional)<br><input id="number" type="number" min="20" max="60" placeholder="Age"><br></label>
        <label for="dropdown">Which option best describes your current role?<br>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown list option">
            <option value="select current role" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select current role</option>
            <option value="student">Student</option>
            <option value="full time job">Full Time Job</option>
            <option value="full time learner">Full Time Learner</option>
            <option value="prefer not to say">Prefer not to say</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    <br></label>
        <p>Would you recommend StartUp to a friend ?
        </p>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="definitely">
        <label>Definitely<br></label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="maybe">
        <label>Maybe<br></label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="not sure">
        <label>Not Sure<br></label>
        <label>
            Which is your favourite feature of StartUp?<br>
            <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown list option ff">
                <option value="select an option" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select and option</option>
                <option value="challenges">Challenges</option>
                <option value="projects">Projects</option>
                <option value="community">Community</option>
                <option value="open source">Open Source</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <p>What would you like to seeimproved? (Check all that apply)</p>
        <input type="checkbox" value="fep">
        <label>Front-end Projects<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="bep">
        <label>Back-end Projects<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="dv">
        <label>Data Visualization<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="c">
        <label>Challenges<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="osc">
        <label>Open Source Community<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="ghr">
        <label>Gitter help rooms<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="v">
        <label>Videos<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="cm">
        <label>City Meetups<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="w">
        <label>Wiki<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="f">
        <label>Forum<br></label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="ac">
        <label>Additional Courses<br></label>
        <label>Any comments or suggestions?<br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="comment">
        </label>
        <label><br><button type="button">Submit</button>
        </label>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the complete CSS code:

```
 body{
        background-image: url(background.jpg);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    h1{
        font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: rgb(216, 213, 28);
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    #description{
        font-family: cursive;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgb(231, 224, 224);
    }
    
    form{
        background-color: rgba(99, 98, 100, 0.9);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Gonna be very difficult to provide any help without showing some code on this issue

Comment: Is it possible to show the HTML code? You can put the form in a div tag and change the margin and padding so the grey background shrinks

Comment: I have uploaded the entire HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

The content should really be in a div tag, also if you want the grey background to be smaller you should use a margin:

```
form {
       margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
     }
```

This will apply margin in the following way: Top, Right, Bottom, Left

Comment: Yeah, using margin the gray background can be shrunk but what about padding. Padding - space between element content and its border. The form element contains various no. of input elements which act as its content, so by using padding space between its content and border should be reduced which should end up resulting in shrinking of the gray background. Kindly help me in this direction of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using  `box-sizing: border-box;` and your body or any other container class is having `max-width:100%;`

```
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```